# Change label text tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I got this code from usingpython.com which is a "type the colour not the word" [game](http://usingpython.com/dl/TTCANTW.py).

I am using this code to build an improved version of this game and something is wrong and I can't figure why.

So, I want to change the label where the words are (named "label"), to something like "Game Over! Your score is bla bla bla" when the countdown hits 0. So, i did this (what I added is just the 2 last lines):

```
def nextColour():

#use the globally declared 'score' and 'play' variables above.
global score
global timeleft

#if a game is currently in play...
if timeleft > 0:

    #...make the text entry box active.
    e.focus_set()

    #if the colour typed is equal to the colour of the text...
    if e.get().lower() == colours[1].lower():
        #...add one to the score.
        score += 1

    #clear the text entry box.
    e.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    #shuffle the list of colours.
    random.shuffle(colours)
    #change the colour to type, by changing the text _and_ the colour to a random colour value
    label.config(fg=str(colours[1]), text=str(colours[0]))
    #update the score.
    scoreLabel.config(text="Score: " + str(score))

elif timeleft == 0:
    ĺabel.config(text="Game Over! Your score is: " + score)
```

This is not working. When the countdown hits 0 the game just does nothing and stops.

I was thinking if I can do this with a while loop...

Answer (score 5):

### Updating a widgets value

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34901558/7455070) for more details.

You can change the text value of a Label widget 'dynamically' using its `textvariable` option with a `StringVar` object, **or** with the `.configure()` method of the `Label` object. As mentioned in the answer above, the `.configure()` method has the benefit of one less object to track

With `textvariable` and `StringVar`:

```
# Use tkinter for Python 3.x
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import Label

root = tk.Tk()

# ...
my_string_var = tk.StringVar(value="Default Value")

my_label = Label(root, textvariable=my_string_var)
my_label.pack()

#Now to update the Label text, simply `.set()` the `StringVar`
my_string_var.set("New text value")
```

With `.configure()`

```
# ...

my_label = Label(root, text="Default string")
my_label.pack()

#NB: .config() can also be used
my_label.configure(text="New String")
```

See [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) for more details.

### Debugging Checks

Without looking at all your code, I would also recommend checking various other issues listed below for possible cause.
To extend on your comments (on this post), there may be various reasons why the program doesn't 'work' as expected:

- The program never enters the final `if` block (`if timeleft == 0`) and so the `.config` method does not get the chance to update the variable
- The global variable `timeleft` does reach `0`, but after that iteration, it increments above `0` and re-enters the first `if` block (`if timeleft>0`), overriding the `.config()` you desire.
- Another part of the code may be calling a `.config()` on your widget and overriding your desired changes

### Planning your GUI

To prevent these things from happening, I highly recommend taking a step back, getting some pen and paper and thinking about the overall design of your application. Specifically ask yourself:

- How can the user interact with this widget? What actions/events will cause changes to this widget?
- Think of all the combinations of these events and ask yourself if these events conflict with one-another.

Also consider drawing a flow-chart for the application, from when the user launches the application to the possible paths they can take before closing, making sure blocks in the flow do not contradict each other.

Finally, also have a look into the [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture (and its [variants](https://manojjaggavarapu.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/presentation-patterns-mvc-mvp-pm-mvvm/)) for good application design

Comment: Note: you don't _have_ to use `textvariable`.  You can change the text by calling the `configure` method on the label.

Comment: Oh, never knew - always been doing it this way without putting much thought to it. Reckon I should take down my answer then? (thought that was the issue)

Comment: You don't have to take down your answer, though I would recommend rewording it slightly so as not to give the impression this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Bryan Oakley, thats was what I was doing and it didn't work. I used label.config....

Comment: I almost got it... But how can i put:
 fg=str(colours[1]), text=str(colours[0])
inside a value =

Comment: @Zitomak that may be an import error, check to see that have imported in the same fashion as I have, **or**, make sure you correctly manage your namespace if you have done `from Tkinter import *`

Comment: I edited my answer cause I had not the import tkinter as tk ;)... But now I've a new problem (edited above)

Comment: This is where `.config()` is more likely to trump the `textvariable`/`StringVar` option (among other reasons), as this method gives you access to all other options in the widget. E.g. `Label.config(fg="red")`

Comment: For diagnosis, does the `textvariable`/`StringVar` option work when you replace the `.config` method? If **not** it may be the case that the program never "enters" the final `if` block

Comment: Yeah, I guess thats what's happening but I don't know why... I thought about making a while loop and when the clock hits 0 it changes... what do you think?

Comment: Haven't tested, but if you individually changed your widget to have a `textvariable` option, it may be the case that other parts of your code that use the `.config ()` method have no more effect over the widget - i.e. a problem with widget management globally

Comment: The textvariable/StringVar isn't working in this case. Now the words don't change. It keeps the same word (the default on the variable) changing the color. I guess it is because textvariable has only one string, and fg=str(colours[1]), text=str(colours[0]) has two

Comment: I'm using label.config() again, and it says: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/miguel/Desktop/stay alive/StayAlive.py", line 25, in startGame
    nextColour()
  File "/home/miguel/Desktop/stay alive/StayAlive.py", line 55, in nextColour
    ĺabel.config(text="Game Over! Your score is: " + score)
NameError: name 'ĺabel' is not defined

Comment: @Zitomak if you modified your imports from `from Tkinter import *` to the way I have used (preferred to not 'pollute' your namespace) then that may have caused issues in your code elsewhere that was relying on you to `import *`. On a side note, notice that the `Label` widget is a class which is **capitalised**, you have used `label` with a lowercase 'l', which may be your issue.

Answer (score -1):

initial label-

```
    lbl_selection_value1=Label(root, text="Search Option 1")
    lbl_selection_value1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=1)
```

updated label-

```
    lbl_selection_value1.destroy()
    lbl_selection_value1_updated = Label(root, text='New Text')
    lbl_selection_value1_updated.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1)
```

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to destroy and recreate a label if all you're doing is changing the text. Plus, in the original question they are using `pack`, so this answer won't work for them.