# Moving data from function to a class

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to pass information from a function into a class. The class holds GUI information in tkinter and the functions some work and output data for the GUI. How can I give the class the output from the function?

Example:

```
class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       #setting up a label to change based off output:
       self.testing_label = tk.Label(self, text='OUTPUT OF WORKER WILL GO HERE', width=20)
       self.testing_label.pack(side="top")

#function that does work:
def worker(x):
    work = x + 5
    return(work)
```

How would I get the returned `work` into the class to be displayed in the label?

Comment: create a object of class and pass the data into constructor (__init__)

Comment: Does `worker` get executed only once (before instantiating `Page1`) or multiple times and you want the label to change each time?

Comment: It will be executed multiple times and the label needs to change each time. Good question

Comment: why wouldn't `text=worker(<param of x>)` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter: Configure method for labels dynamically generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901039/tkinter-configure-method-for-labels-dynamically-generated)

Comment: How are you calling `worker`? Does the function that calls `worker` have a reference to the page object? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The `worker` function is being called by a button click that is not referenced in the `Page1` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the value of a variable in an instance of any class, all you need is a reference to that class. You can either pass that in to `worker`, or make sure that whatever calls `worker` has a reference to that page.

Without seeing more of your code it's impossible to give a specific example. Based solely on what is in your question, you would do it something like this:

```
def worker(x):
    work = x + 5
    return(work)
...
page = Page()
...
result = worker(42)
page.testing_label.configure(text=str(result))
```

Even better would be for the page to provide an interface so that the caller doesn't have to know the names of internal widgets. For example:

```
class Page1(Page):
    ...
    def set_result(self, string):
        self.testing_label.configure(text=string)
...
page = Page1()
...
result = worker(42)
page.set_result(result)
```

Note that if `worker` is actually a method inside of `Page1`, you could make it work like this:

```
class Page1(Page):
    ...
    def worker(self, x):
        work = x + 5
        self.testing_label.configure(text=str(work))
```

Comment: This got me on the right track, however the label itself is not changing. I crated another question with that is more specific. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683486/moving-data-from-function-to-a-class